# Missing pushups in UFC Trainer

Tags: kinect, ufc-personal-trainer

I am about 3 days into my first 30-day challenge on *UFC Trainer* and have been getting frustrated that the game isn't picking up all of my push-ups.

I can grind out 20 or so ( don't laugh (; ) in the allotted time, but can barely get the game to register 12 or 13. Does anyone have any tips on getting all of my push-ups to count? I've tried going slower, adjusting the angle of the Kinect, and adjusting the angle of my head while I do push-ups, but nothing seems to make a difference. I am thinking it is something to do with being low to the floor, as I experience some trouble with situps as well.

I'm working out on hardwood floors, could that make a difference?

Comment: Like a real trainer : "You think this was a push up? This one doesn't count, KEEP GOING!"

Comment: This seems to be a common complaint with all workout games for the 360 - in fact, with all workout games, period. Motion detection is still not precise enough to cover exercises well enough; the best answer here should help, but you'll likely have some issues no matter what you try.

Comment: @Eric Ha! I like that answer. I'll replay that in my head every time I heard that "be-urb" sound it makes for a failed movement!

Comment: @Dave, thanks for the broader answer regarding all workout games. After this experience, I could definitely see it being a problem. But all flaws aside, and maybe its just because it is still new to me, I still think the Kinect is an amazing piece of technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kinect isn't really optimized for people laying on the floor - the angle and distance that Microsoft recommends is really designed for people standing up or (potentially) sitting on a couch.  I seem to remember reading that the "sitting on the couch" use case to be one they added support for late in the project.

Even standing up, the Kinect doesn't really have 100% accuracy.  My family is usually repeatedly frustrated trying to play games with it, even though we've done everything we can to make the Kinect work optimally.

For lying on the floor, you're going to have to experiment with the position and angle of the sensor to get the best results.  If it's on top of your TV, try moving it lower.  If it's low already, try moving it higher.  You may need to get slightly further or closer to the sensor as well.  Run the Kinect Tuner between adjustments to give the Kinect the best chance of finding you.

Your motion during the exercise may also matter.  Generally, the more motion and the more your distance from the sensor changes, the better chances you have at being detected.  However, some of this depends on the game as well as the Kinect.

Unfortunately, it's hard to say what's going to work best - [people reporting similar problems](http://www.ufcpersonaltrainer.com/uk/forums/topic/18366) said their solutions ran the gamut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer agent86. I didn't know if there was a better way to position the sensor or if it was a limitation of the technology. Seems like a limitation of the sensor. Thanks for the link as well, glad its not just me.

Comment: Just an update, the Kinect seems to track my pushups better when I consistently face the camera. This is poor form, I know, but better for capturing reps. Perhaps the camera is expecting a human face in order to "compute" my virtual body?